# Predict down years/rows based on previous years/rows, with lmer and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lme4, predict

I have a linear mixed effects model that determines change in grass based on both the previous year's grass and several environmental variables (and their interaction) at different distinct sites over time.

Using this mixed effects model and established, projected future environmental variables, I want to predict change in grass density. Each year's prediction thus depends on the previous year's density, located on the row above it in my dataframe. We begin with a real value from the present year, and then predict into the future.

```
library(tidyverse); library(lme4)

#data we have from the past, where each site has annual ChlA/Sal/Temp as well as grass density. our formula, change.mod, predicts grass.change, based on these env variables AND last year's grass coverage (grass.y1)
ThePast = tibble( 
  year = c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021,2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021),
  site = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  ChlA = c(50, 210, 190, 101, 45, 20, 20, 80, 5, 40, 25, 12, 11, 5, 20),
  Sal= c(1, 4, 5, 0.1, 10, 18, 14, 17, 10, 21, 30, 28, 25, 20, 22), 
  Temp = c(28, 21, 24, 25, 22, 19, 20, 17, 18, 15, 18, 16, 19, 20, 20), 
  grass = c(.5, .3, .1, .4, .1, .25, .33, .43, .44, .08, .75, .54, .69, .4, .6)) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(grass.y1 = lag(grass, order_by = year)) %>% #last year's grass
  mutate(grass.change = grass - grass.y1) %>% #calculate change
 ungroup()

#the ME model
change.mod = lmer(grass.change ~ grass.y1 + log10(ChlA) + log10(Sal) + grass.y1:log10(Temp) + grass.y1:log10(Sal) + (1|site), data = ThePast) 

#Future environmental data per site per year, to be used to predict grass.
TheDistantFuture <- tibble(
  year = c(2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2024, 2024), 
  site = c( "A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), 
  ChlA = c(40, 200, 10, 95, 10, 4, 149, 10, 15), 
  Sal= c(12, 11, 15, 16, 21, 32, 21, 21, 22), 
  Temp = c(24, 22, 26, 28, 29, 32, 31, 20, 18))

#The final dataframe should look like this, where both of the grass columns are predicted out into the future. could have the grass.y1 column in here if we wanted
PredictedFuture <- tibble(
  year = c(2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2024, 2024), 
  site = c( "A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), 
  ChlA = c(40, 200, 10, 95, 10, 4, 149, 10, 15), 
  Sal= c(12, 11, 15, 16, 21, 32, 21, 21, 22), 
  Temp = c(24, 22, 26, 28, 29, 32, 31, 20, 18), 
  grass = c(0.237, 0.335, 0.457, 0.700, 0.151, 0.361, 0.176, 0.380, 0.684), 
  grass.change = c(0.1368, 0.2550, -0.1425, -0.1669, -0.18368, -0.0962, 0.106, 0.229, 0.323 ))
```

Right now, I can generate the next year's (2022) correct predictions using group_by() and predict(), referencing last year's grass density with a lag function.

```
#How do we get to PredictedFuture?? Here is what I'm trying:

FutureIsNow = ThePast %>%
  filter(year == 2021) %>% #take last year of real data to have baseline starting grass density
  bind_rows(TheDistantFuture) %>% #bind future data
  arrange(site, year) %>% #arrange by site then year
  group_by(site) %>% #maybe this should be rowwise?
  mutate(grass.change = predict(change.mod, newdata = data.frame(
    grass.y1 = lag(grass, n = 1, order_by = year), 
    ChlA = ChlA, Sal = Sal, Temp = Temp, site = site))) %>% #this correctly predicts 2022 grass change
  mutate(grass = grass.change + lag(grass, n = 1)) #this also works to calculate grass in 2022
```

This df looks like this:

```
> FutureIsNow
# A tibble: 12 × 7
# Groups:   site [3]
    year site   ChlA   Sal  Temp  grass grass.change
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>
 1  2021 A        45    10    22 NA           NA    
 2  2022 A        40    12    24  0.237        0.137
 3  2023 A        95    16    28 NA           NA    
 4  2024 A       149    21    31 NA           NA    
 5  2021 B        40    21    15 NA           NA    
 6  2022 B       200    11    22  0.335        0.255
 7  2023 B        10    21    29 NA           NA    
 8  2024 B        10    21    20 NA           NA    
 9  2021 C        20    22    20 NA           NA    
10  2022 C        10    15    26  0.457       -0.143
11  2023 C         4    32    32 NA           NA    
12  2024 C        15    22    18 NA           NA
```

Close, but not really repeatable...

Any ideas for predicting grass change for 2023, 2024, down the rows? I prefer working in tidyverse, though it may be possible to solve this more easily with nested for loops. Potential solutions include a [rowwise](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/rowwise.html) data structure, or maybe to nest_by(station), but I don't know how to then reference the grass.y1 column. Maybe the solution could be via a rolling prediction with [rollify](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/tibbletime/vignettes/TT-03-rollify-for-rolling-analysis.html#rolling-regressions), but I am not sure!

Thank you in advance for your help! Long time reader, first time asker!

Answer (score 0):

So, let's go with a simpler example here for a reprex to show how `purrr::accumulate2()` can work for you here.

Let's setup a discrete time population model where there is also some covariate that affects time

$N_t = 1.5N_{t-1} + C$

Simple! Heck, we can even use accumulate2 to simulate a population, and then add some noise.

```
library(tidyverse)


# ok, let's make a population from a simple discrete time growth model
# but, with a covariate!
covariate <- runif(5, 5, 10)

# use accumulate2 with the covariate to generate a population timeseries
pop <- accumulate2(1:5,covariate, ~.x*1.5 + .y, .init = 0) %>% unlist()
pop <- pop[-1]
pop_obs <- rnorm(5, pop, 1) #add some noise
```

Great! Now, turn it into data and fit a model

```
# the data ####
dat <- tibble(
    time = 1:5,
    covariate = covariate,
    pop_obs = pop_obs,
    lag_pop = lag(pop_obs)
)


# the model ####
mod <- lm(pop_obs ~ covariate + lag_pop, data = dat)

# does this look reasonable?
coef(mod)
```

My coefficients looked reasonable, but, set a seed and see!

Now we will need some data we want to simulate for - new covariates, but, we will need to incorporate the lag.

```
# now, simulation data ####
simdat <- tibble(
    time = 6:10,
    covariate = runif(5, 15,20),
    lag_pop = dat$pop_obs[5] #the last lagged value!
)
```

Great! To make this work, we'll need a function that takes arguments of the lagged value and covariate and runs a prediction. Note, here the second argument is just a numeric. But, you could pass an element of a list - a row of a data frame, if you will. This might be accomplished later with some rowwise nesting or somesuch. For you to work out!

```
# OK, now we need to get predictions for pop at each step in time! ####
sim_pred <- function(lag_pop, covariate){
    newdat <- tibble(covariate = covariate,
                     lag_pop = lag_pop)
    
    predict(mod, newdata = newdat)
}
```

With this in hand, we can simulate forward using lag_pop to generate a new population. Note, we'll need to use `.init` to make sure our first value is correct as well as strip off the final value (I think...might want to check that)

```
# and let her rip!
# note, we have to init with the first value and 
# for multiple covariates, make a rowwise list - 
# each element of the list is 
# one row of the data and the sim_pred function takes it apart
simdat %>%
    mutate(pop = accumulate2(lag_pop, 
                             covariate,
                             ~sim_pred(.x, .y),
                             .init = lag_pop[1]) %>% `[`(-1) %>% unlist())
```

That should do!